# What causes these two regexes to work differently?

Tags: java, regex

I am using the following regex in a Java calculator program to tokenize input:

`((?<=[(^+/*-])|(?=[(^+/*-]))`

I was previously using this regex (note that the caret is moved to the end):

`((?<=[(+/*-^])|(?=[(+/*-^]))`

This one caused problems because multi-digit inputs would be cut up into individual characters. i.e., "11" would split into "1", "1".

I know that the caret is a special character at the front of a character class, but why does it cause the regex to work improperly when placed at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `[(+/*-^]`, `*-^` matches characters in the range `*` to `^`, that's your problem.

But when you write `[(^+/*-]`, it matches one of `(`, `^`, `+`, `/`, `*` or `-`.

Clearer example:

- `[12a-z]` will match `1`, `2` or a character between `a` and `z`
- `[12az-]` matches `1`, `2`, `a`, `z` or `-`